# How to add data to an existing excel sheet using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I have the data generated as follows using javascript.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/profiledatanew',
      data: {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#id").text(data.id)
        $("#name").text(data.name)
        $("#relationship_status").text(data.relationship_status);
        $("#gender").text(data.gender)
        $("#hometown").text(data.hometown.name);
        var list = $("#checkinslist");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.tagged_places.data.length; i++) {
          for (obj in data.tagged_places.data[i]) {
            list.append("<li>" + data.tagged_places.data[i].place.name + "</li>");
          }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

And I have the excel sheet which I have prepared before as in the following format:

[image]

How to add the data I generate to this excel file? I went on several examples but none of those worked out.

Comment: If this runs in a browser: no way to get it working, a browser script simply can't access local files. If it runs elsewhere, then you need to be much more specific about how, where & what.

Comment: where exactly is this excel file located? Either way your browser has no direct access to it. Also, you are generating HTML in your code, not Excel data. Are you sure this is the right design for achieving this task? Your code and you stated goal seem very disconnected from each other. I would have thought this task would be better performed using some server-side script. But if the spreadsheet is actually located on the end-user's machine (not the server) then as PeterB mentions, you can forget the whole thing, unless you write a desktop (not web-based) app